# use of boolean to color converter in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters

I am working on WPF application.I have bound my textblock to my button. I want to set foreground of my textblock to black color when its associated button's isEnabled is true.
I want to do this using converter. **But its not working**. also not giving any error.
I have declared following class in my "Models" folder.

```
public class BrushColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value)
        {
            {
                return System.Windows.Media.Colors.Black;
            }
        }
        return System.Windows.Media.Colors.LightGreen;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Button's enable,isable property changes from viewmodel**(e.g using RaiseCanExecuteChanged)())

textblock related things in XAML are:

```
   <Window.Resources>
            <local:BrushColorConverter x:Key="BConverter"></local:BrushColorConverter>
   </Window.Resources>
<Button>(!..all button properties..!)</Button>
    <TextBlock x:Name="AnswerText"                                           
               Text="Answer"                                          
               Foreground="{Binding ElementName=AnswerButton,Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BConverter}}"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

Comment: Try out returning string: `System.Windows.Media.Colors.Black.ToString()`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

use
return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

Comment: Thanks. that is more accurate, since I am able to return the color directly instead of returning 'string'.

Answer (score 21):

The answer above shows you how to correctly you use a converter. However, do you really need to use a converter? This can be done in XAML only using `Triggers`:

**XAML**

```
        <StackPanel>

            <Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=isEnabledCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}">
                <TextBlock Text="Answer" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </Button>

            <Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=isEnabledCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}">
                <TextBlock Text="Answer" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </Button>

            <CheckBox x:Name="isEnabledCheckBox" Content="Toggle IsEnable on Buttons above" />

        </StackPanel>
```

In the example above, the first `TextBlock` binds to its parent's `IsEnabled` property using a `DataTrigger`, and sets the `Foreground` to some colour if it is true.

However, this is overkill - the `IsEnabled` property is propagated down to children automatically by WPF. That is, if you set `IsEnabled` to false on your `Button`, then your `TextBlock` will have its `IsEnabled` property updated to false automatically. This is demonstrated in the second `TextBlock` which uses a property `Trigger` to check its own `IsEnabled` property against the value of true (since its `IsEnabled` property will be the same as its parent's). This would be the preferred approach.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is also a great work. I tried same earlier but I wasn't able to bind to its parents. But relativesource will solve that problem. Thanks.

Comment: This won't work if your using some like [Material Design in XAML](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit), because setting the style trigger overwrites the entire material design style of the control.

Answer (score 14):

To make this converter general you may use a `ConverterParameter` for specifying the colors which is to be inserted when `value` is true or false. Also the opacity may be of interest. I here provide the Converter I taking the parameter [ColorNameIfTrue;ColorNameIfFalse;OpacityNumber].

Since the `SolidColorBrush()` method mentioned by @user1101511 is part of the `System.Windows.Media` library, it uses the `Color` type from that same library. This type does not have a `Color.FromName()` method, like the `System.Drawing.Color` class.

Therfore I made a helper method called `ColorFromName(string name)`. I specify `"LimeGreen"` as a fallback color if the interpertation of `ConverterParameter` fails. In my case I want the output to be `"Transparent"` when `value` is false.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace MyConverters
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(SolidColorBrush))]
    class BoolToColorBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region Implementation of IValueConverter

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Bolean value controlling wether to apply color change</param>
        /// <param name="targetType"></param>
        /// <param name="parameter">A CSV string on the format [ColorNameIfTrue;ColorNameIfFalse;OpacityNumber] may be provided for customization, default is [LimeGreen;Transperent;1.0].</param>
        /// <param name="culture"></param>
        /// <returns>A SolidColorBrush in the supplied or default colors depending on the state of value.</returns>
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SolidColorBrush color;
        // Setting default values
        var colorIfTrue = Colors.LimeGreen;
        var colorIfFalse = Colors.Transparent;
        double opacity = 1;
        // Parsing converter parameter
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            // Parameter format: [ColorNameIfTrue;ColorNameIfFalse;OpacityNumber]
            var parameterstring = parameter.ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameterstring))
            {
                var parameters = parameterstring.Split(';');
                var count = parameters.Length;
                if (count > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters[0]))
                {
                    colorIfTrue = ColorFromName(parameters[0]);
                }
                if (count > 1 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters[1]))
                {
                    colorIfFalse = ColorFromName(parameters[1]);
                }
                if (count > 2 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters[2]))
                {
                    double dblTemp;
                    if (double.TryParse(parameters[2], NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, out dblTemp))
                        opacity = dblTemp;
                }
            }
        }
        // Creating Color Brush
        if ((bool) value)
        {
            color = new SolidColorBrush(colorIfTrue);
            color.Opacity = opacity;
        }
        else
        {
            color = new SolidColorBrush(colorIfFalse);
            color.Opacity = opacity;
        }
        return color;
    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion

    public static Color ColorFromName(string colorName)
    {
        System.Drawing.Color systemColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(colorName);
        return Color.FromArgb(systemColor.A, systemColor.R, systemColor.G, systemColor.B);
    }
}
```

From xaml the above converter may be used like this:

```
Background="{Binding MyBooleanValue, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorBrushConverter}, ConverterParameter=LimeGreen;Transperent;0.2, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Comment: Best answer here!