# Change border color depending on boolean value

Tags: wpf, xaml, converters

I have a border wihch I want to change its color depending on a boolean variable. I used the [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533546/use-of-boolean-to-color-converter-in-xaml) to implement a `Boolean` to `Color` converter.

The code looks like this:

**The xaml:**

```
<Border Width="45" 
     Height="45" CornerRadius="5" 
     Background="{Binding Path=LivenessActive, Converter={StaticResource BrushColorConverter}}" />
```

**The LivenessActive variable in background:**

```
public bool LivenessActive
{
  get { return _livenessActive; }
  set
  {
      _livenessActive = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("LivenessActive");
  }
}
```

Where the class has an inheritance to the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has implemented the `OnPropertyChanged` event.

**The BrushColorConverter.cs:**

```
public class BrushColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value)
        {
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.GreenYellow);
            }
        }
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

But I can't fire even the `BrushColorConverter`. What I'm doing wrong?

**2nd: What about if I want to use it from an another Window?**

```
<Border Width="45" Height="45" CornerRadius="5" 
     Background="{Binding Path=LivenessActive, Converter={StaticResource BrushColorConverter}, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type view:MyWindowName}}}" />
```

I used this same code and it's not finding it.

Comment: I see nothing wrong in this code. Where is `LivenessActive` defined? Is `DataContext` set accordingly?

Comment: True... The DataContext!! How could I forgot it... Please, post your answer so I can upvote it...

Comment: What about if I want to use it from an external Window? See my edit.

Comment: So you have 2 `Border`s in 2 different `Window`s and you want to link them one property?

Comment: Yes, 2 borders in 2 different Windows. I want them to link to the same property located in the same .cs.

Comment: You need to set `DataContext` in both windows to same instance of view model, if this is the place where `LivenessActive` defined

Comment: Again, completely perfect! Please, post both answers so I can upvote you. You made my day happier! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum up comments since there seems to be nothing wrong with code above it would suggest there is a problem with binding context for

```
Background="{Binding Path=LivenessActive, Converter={StaticResource BrushColorConverter}}"
```

You cannot reference one `Window` from another `Window`. If you have 2 independent `Window`s each with `Border` that should trigger on the same property change then you set `DataContext` of both windows to same instance of view model.