# How Can I change listbox's textboxes apearance depending on object that goes there?

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, uwp, observablecollection

Im new here, I have built this small uwp app using binded ObservableCollection to a Listbox, I wanted to know how to change apearence of Textbox inside listbox. To be precise I have ObservableCollection which is made out of objects and one property of this object is a boolean. "UsersWithIndications.CheckedInOrOut" = boolean. I want to make it so if this boolean is true, textbox of this single User becomes green, if its false = red... Can You please show me a direction of resolving this issue? How can I access each individual textbox in this Listbox? If any more code is required, please let me know!

Xaml code for the page
[image: Xaml code for the page]

App Launched, Listbox

[image: App Launched, Listbox]

Comment: Easiest way to do it is using a separate property for Foreground color

Comment: Just FYI - it is much better if you can post the XAML (& any other code) as text in your question - rather than add a screen shot - it is much easier for us to read. Also if we want to test an idea before posting - it is possible to cut & paste the code. To show it as a code section - just indent by 4 spaces.

Comment: Use a custom converter on the TextBlock's Foreground property. See this as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533546/use-of-boolean-to-color-converter-in-xaml 

(this uses WPF and UWP's IValueConverter interface is a little bit different, but intellisense can fill tht out for you)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I guess the separate property is easiest way since this app is just for testing purposes. I'll look in to converters too tho. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1:

**Using Converter**

Here is the code for Converter

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if ((string)value == "true")
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        else
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is the code Data Binding

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<TextBlock Name="MyOutput" Text="true" Foreground="{Binding Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ElementName=MyOutput}"/>
```

### Method 2:

Using separate property for `Foreground` color