# I want to change the line color using 'button trigger' in a specific condition

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to change the color of line1 and line2 like below.
How can I bind a variable in c# code?
Is there a good solution to resolve the code below?

- xaml code

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Width="6" Height="6" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,14,0">
            <Line x:Name="line1" X1="0" Y1="0" X2="6" Y2="6" Stroke="#BDC4CF" StrokeThickness="1"/>
            <Line x:Name="line2" X1="0" Y1="6" X2="6" Y2="0" Stroke="#BDC4CF" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="line1" Property="Stroke" Value="{binding linecolor}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="line2" Property="Stroke" Value="{binding linecolor}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

- c# code

```
public bool IsChecked
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
        ToggleBtn.IsChecked = value;

        if(isPicked == true)
        {
            linecolor = (Brush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#3EF79B"));
        }
        else
        {
            linecolor = (Brush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FFFFFF"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into `Converters` yet? [IValueConverter usage](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/868163/IValueConverter-Example-and-Usage-in-WPF)

Comment: I don't need checkbox. I just want to bind color to a variable.

Comment: You can take your value and make it a color. [Here is a color example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533546/use-of-boolean-to-color-converter-in-xaml).

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the following looks like: `IsCheckedProperty`, `isPicked`, `linecolor` ?

Comment: I have left you an answer of how i would approach your issue. Did it solve your issue or is there something else to your problem? Please let us know so we can have an answer on this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to rethink your approach here.
First there is some unknown stuff. 
Only thing i will assume is that your `isPicked` boolean is a property.

The way i would go about it is using a [ValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter?view=netframework-4.8)

So first of all in the `DataContext` of your view i would have the `IsPicked` property:

```
private bool isPicked;
public bool IsPicked
{
    get { return isPicked; }
    set { isPicked = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Then i would create a new .cs file for the converter:

```
class BoolToColor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? "#3EF79B" : "#FFFFFF";
        /*Same as:
        if((bool)value) 
        {
            return "#3EF79B";
        } 
        else 
        {
            return "#FFFFFF";
        }*/
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

then lastly set it all up in the view (In this case i used a `Window`):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToColor x:Key="BoolToColor" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Width="50" Height="50" Click="Button_Click" />
    <Grid Width="20" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,14,0">
        <Line x:Name="line1" X1="0" Y1="0" X2="20" Y2="20" Stroke="{Binding IsPicked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColor}}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        <Line x:Name="line2" X1="0" Y1="20" X2="20" Y2="0" Stroke="{Binding IsPicked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColor}}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

But wait there is a button? Yes, i added a button to test the color change.
Here is the code for the `Button_Click`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IsPicked = !IsPicked;
}
```

Lastly i hope you get the idea that instead of a button you can change the property value of `IsPicked` to set the color. I hope this will help you continue on your project :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved this problem thanks to you! Actually, I didn't use the converter. I just accessed "line1" and "line2" and changed stroke by using IsChecked like this: line1.Stroke = (Brush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#3EF79B"));

Comment: Good to hear you found an answer. 
The reason i would use a Converter is mainly too keep front and back end separate. 
But it looks like it is not needed in this scenario. Happy coding :)