# Styling a status bar in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

In my C# application I would like to display a list of boolean values in the status bar.
Each value has a label and those with a value of true are green and those that are false should be red
I have read about how to render a list but cannot get colors to work.

How can this be done?

Comment: You can either do it via `IValueConverter` or `Sytle` to change true to green and false to red color.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, I am a newbie at this stuff - please can you supply more details

Comment: Check the thread --- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533546/use-of-boolean-to-color-converter-in-xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533546/use-of-boolean-to-color-converter-in-xaml)

Comment: This thread solved it for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533546/use-of-boolean-to-color-converter-in-xaml

Comment: The answer was found in the link provided by user1672994
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533546/use-of-boolean-to-color-converter-in-xaml