# C# wpf mvvm programmatically change border color programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, border

I'm a beginner - I have a Border with an image inside, there could ultimately be many of these border/photos in xaml code.
The border(s) have an attribute Name="Border_N" (N = a unique border id value) I'd like to click on this photo which is a button and have the border change colour.
I want to be able do this programmatically but, I'm really not sure how best to go about this. I'm sure this can't be difficult, but I'm really not sure where to start. Anyone know?

Comment: First of all, you should clarify your requirements. What happens on the second click? Does the color change back to the value it had before the first click? Then consider using a ToggleButton. If it is a ToggleButton, bind the Border's BorderBrush to the IsChecked property of the ToggleButton with an appropriate Binding Converter.

Comment: This is a fair point. So far I have been able to display an ObservableCollection of names from MySQL to my MainWindow. Each name has an `Id`. When I click on it, I want to send this names Id back to MySQL and change the Border color. "What happens on the second click?" ...to be continue.

Comment: If you are a beginner, learn MVVM. As the meme says, first you have to learn the rules, so that then you can break them like a pro. If you try to start by breaking the rules you are in for big disappointment and great pain.

Comment: And chances are, that once you have learned the rules, you will not even have the desire to break them, because you will see that MVVM does in fact make GUI development so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to change your border color programmatically. You do not even want to change your border color when something is clicked. What you want to do instead is to introduce some state in your viewmodel, which represents the fact that "this photo" is clicked, (say, `bool ThisPhotoIsClicked { get; set; }`, hopefully you will find a more meaningful name,) and then you want to make your border select its color based on that state.

For this, you have a couple of options:

- You can bind the color of the border to the state using a binding with a boolean-to-color converter (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32526689/773113)
- You can assign a style to your border which incorporates triggers to realize different colors based on different states (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8534694/773113)

Comment: If he just wants to highlight every clicked photo and never wants to go back, introducing MVVM is an overkill IMO. Handling Visuals in code behind is perfectly fine. Sure he should consider using MVVM if it is appropriate but how do you know?

Comment: I'm trying to learn the mechanisms, so to speak. I've used MySQL, added images to buttons etc. If I can work out how to effect a xaml border or label or anyting else programmatically I'll be very happy.

Comment: @lorenzalbert I begin with the axiom that WPF cannot legitimately be used without MVVM, and more broadly, that GUI development is only worth doing using MVVM.  In the past I have used C++/Win32 GDI, C++/MFC, C#/WinForms, Java/Swing, and Java/SWT, so trust me when I say, that's the way to go.

Comment: @user1192941 yes, and precisely because you are trying to learn the mechanisms I am pointing you to ***The Mechanisms***.  If it was obvious from your question that you were already quite familiar with *The Mechanisms* and you are now just looking for some hacky workaround to bypass *The Mechanisms* and haphazardly accomplish something in a quick and dirty way, then maybe my answer would have been different.

Comment: "quick and dirty" is not my way. I am trying to learn MVVM as mentioned.

Comment: Changing visuals from within the codebehind is not quick and dirty. This also follows the MVVM principle. What you need depends on your use case. As a beginner I'd tell you: "Discover the different functionalities like ClickEvents, how to change visuals from the code behind. Then go on to MVVM and learn how to use Bindings and when to use Commands". Same goes for TDD, IOC and so on. Noone starts learning how to code by jumping into these topics.